# Redirect 301 for entire site with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been unable to find a reliable solution to this.

I want to redirect all of a domain to a new domain, i.e.

www.olddomain.com/post236 redirects to www.newdomain/posts236

But I have a couple of exceptions

i.e. www.olddomain.com/about-us/ redirects to www.newdomain.com/about/

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Redirects in htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/about-us/?$ http://newdomain.com/about
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1
```

Note : The second line redirects all requests from old domain. If you have more exceptions on redirects ,just put them above this.